# Powershell and a path as an argument that is double-quote delimited

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a simple PS script that needs to accept a parameter that happens to be a path to a directory.  I get this path handed to me and invoke the ps script as follows:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -F "C:\temp\ctest\logging test\postinstall.ps1" "C:\temp\ctest\logging test\"
```

I cannot control the addition of the '\' to the path that is the param to this script, and it must be double-quoted to account for the space in the path.  So, what I wind up with is a variable inside my ps script that is the string:

```
C:\temp\ctest\logging test"     <<-- error in path!  with the double-quote char. :(
```

My question is simple, I hope, yet I cannot locate anyone who has solved it, yet.  Is there no way to tell powershell not to escape that last double-quote in this scenario?

Thank you for your time, and for educating me.

Comment: side answer if your path in the arg is cut at the first space: I solved it by directly quoting the arg `%1` (in my case it was inside the registry) and escaping the quote which gives: `\"%1\"` . I can then use the `$arg` without any problem (the path doesn't break anymore at the first space).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue looks to be only when invoked from CMD. In your script you could do this:

```
$args[0].TrimEnd('"')
```

It will remove a trailing double quote if one exists.

Or you could double up the backslash:

```
C:\>powershell.exe -f C:\echo.ps1 "C:\temp\ctest\logging test\\"
```

Contents of echo.ps1

```
Write-Host ('"{0}"' -f $args[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -F 'C:\temp\ctest\logging test\postinstall.ps1' 'C:\temp\ctest\logging test\'
```

Comment: that returns immediately from PS with: Processing -File ''C:\temp\ctest\logging test\postinstall.ps1'' failed: The given path's format is not supported. Specify a valid path for the -File parameter.

Comment: Single quoting everything produces: Processing -File ''C:\Temp\ctest\logging test\postinstall.ps1'' failed: The given path's format is not supported. Specify a valid path for the -File parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried single-quoting your argument in your invocation?

Comment: Single quoting the parameter to the ps1 script produces an error when we try to do a dir command on that parameter inside the ps script: Get-ChildItem : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name ''C' does not exist.